# Error: cy.visit from a component spec is not allowed

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to follow the Cypress [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/end-to-end-testing/writing-your-first-end-to-end-test). In the documentation, there is a block of code that is provided to test Cypress:

```
describe('My First Test', () => {
  it('Visits the Kitchen Sink', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
  })
})
```

But when I copied the code block and paste it under cypress.component and run it, there is an error saying

> cy.visit from a component spec is not allowed

How to solve this issue? Did I configure Cypress incorrectly?

[Picture of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO7Ch.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1b8f.jpg)

Comment: That example is simply **not** for the component testing; it's for the E2E testing. Hence the error message.

Comment: But I followed the steps in doing the E2E testing, it still didn't work

Comment: You've provided _screenshots_, and they don't even seem to match each other, so who knows what you've done (we need a [mre] - please take the [tour] and read [ask]). But the message seems clear.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify @jonrsharpe's comment: Try putting the tests in `cypress/e2e` instead of `cypress/component`.

> Test files are located in `cypress/e2e` by default
>
> - [Cypress Documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/writing-and-organizing-tests#Spec-files)

[Cypress Component Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/overview) is meant for testing components that you build in a framework such as Vue or React. When you test components, you are testing the HTML and JS directly rather than running a full blown browser (or "End to End" testing). Since you aren't testing the component in a browser, there is no way to `cy.visit()` a URL.